# How to run a jquery function with specific time using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need some help out there.
I am a newbie for this.
I want to record an audio in which there is an specific time for the recorder to play and stop after the allocated time without clicking the button. How to this using jquery.

**my current code:**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    elem = $(this);
    Fr.voice.record($("#live").is(":checked"), function () {
        elem.addClass("disabled");
        $("#live").addClass("disabled");
        $(".one").removeClass("disabled");
    });
}, 2000);
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval(function(),2000) instead , you can add some checks example: if time start or time end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code, it will give you an alert, once 20 seconds are over after the page has loaded, and you can perform your operation in the else part.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    elem = $(this);
    Fr.voice.record($("#live").is(":checked"), function () {
        var millisec = 1; //starting milli seconds
        var rectime = 20000; // this is the length of the record clip in milli seconds.

        recursiverecording();
        function recursiverecording() {
            millisec = millisec + 1;
            if (millisec < 20000) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    recursiverecording()
                }, 1);
            } else {
                elem.addClass("disabled");
                $("#live").addClass("disabled");
                $(".one").removeClass("disabled");
                alert('your 20 seconds are over gentleman!');
            }
        }
    });
}, 1);
```